# Cannot close AddThis popup on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I'm inserting AddThis share button on a site.

```
var addthis_config =
    {
        services_compact:'facebook,twitter,linkedin,more'
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=......">
```

HTML:

```
<a class="addthis_button">Share</a>
```

It works fine on desktop (on hover). But on iPad the popup shows up when I click the button and then there's no way to close the popup.
I want the popup to close on second click or anywhere on a page.
How can this be done?

Steps to reproduce: Open [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngc72zco/) on iPad, click Share. Popup will show up, there's no way to close it.

Comment: How do you hide the popup on desktop? And why can't you do it the same on mobile?

Comment: I'm not doing anything other than I described in the question. All behavior is handled by AddThis script.

Comment: Is that window/popup an iframe by chance?

Comment: No, it's just a div

Comment: Then where is the problem?